# Cant raise a Support case

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, account

My Snowflake account has been disconnected from duo and I have now lost all access to my snowflake environment. I'm trying to get hold of support but I the automated service wont validate my account and I don't have a Sales person I can talk to.
How can I get back access to my account??

Comment: This question doesn't follow the Stack Overflow guidelines. Please read the [help] for more information about what is considered on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CharlieFish I get that this shouldn't be where i ask the question but it is also the place snowflake lists as their community support area. Unless you know of a better place to ask I dont know where else I should be going.

Comment: Just because a company lists Stack Overflow as their community support page doesn’t mean you can violate Stack Overflow guidelines. I’m not sure how you think we can help you. This is clearly an issue between you and the company. Community members can’t help at all.

Comment: Please try support@snowflake.com with your specifics